# "Something-Else" install 18.04 over 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I've recently learned that if I use the "Something-else" install option, and install Ubuntu 18.04 over my existing 16.04, it will keep track of my installed packages and, versions permitting, reinstall them when the installation is completed.

When I've tried to use `do-release-upgrade`, however, I've been informed that the upgrader needs to remove all of my non-Ubuntu repositories and installed packages to proceed.  While I can understand why this is needed, it's very inconvenient because it greatly increases the time I need to spend on the process.

Is the "reinstall packages" support present in the upgrader as well as the "something-else" install?  And if it is, does that also include third-part repositories and packages like current versions of Wine, SeaMonkey browser suite, or Skype?

Comment: The `do-release-upgrade` script should remove all PPA/3rd party sources, which I believe need to be re-enabled post-install - thus those packages will not be found using a 'something-else' no-format install. The note-of-packages & restoration-of-packages is intended for Ubuntu repository sourced packages, and should not be relied on for 3rd party packages  (ie. Ubuntu main/universe/multiverse/restricted; though I've only every used main & universe with it)   It's also something-else only I believe  (you cannot format for it to occur; most options want to format)

Comment: Also of note:  more packages are now snaps instead of deb packages; and the feature works only with deb packages as far as I know  (although as `chromium-browser` on my system was still installed as a deb which then installed the real snap package; it'll likely work with packages setup this way)

Comment: So we're getting just like Windows -- "You aren't supported because you installed something you didn't buy from us.  Good luck getting your system to ever work again. Oh, and we don't even support our own packages."  I have no snaps to date, as far as I know (don't know if 16.04 even supports them).

Comment: "I've been informed that the upgrader needs to remove all of my non-Ubuntu repositories and installed packages to proceed." This is **wrong**. The upgrader does not *remove* the PPAs or the installed packages. The upgrader comments the source of PPA loctions out in the list. After the upgrade you have to uncomment (enable) the PPA and replace the reference to 16.04 (xanial) with that of 18.04 (bionic).

Comment: @user68186 I might have slightly misremembered the message from the upgrade script -- "disable" seems rather similar to "remove" when I'm about to replace the entire operating system with a newer one.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Non-Ubuntu packages do not need to follow Ubuntu packaging rules (there's no way to enforce them anyway, and versions are often used that ensure upgrade for the aimed release; but this causes the failed upgrade to the next release so very often).  I discovered this issue the first package I made... but many packagers just don't learn it, not caring about minefields created when the next LTS release which is nearly 2 years away....  Ubuntu/Canonical have considered snaps which is why they've been installing them via debs (so it is handled .. currently anyway). 14.04 coped with snaps!

Answer (score 0):

many things changed in 18.04 LTS and my modest recommendation after several upgrades from 16.04 to 18.04 is:
1.) Install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (latest version !) over the existing 16.04, and
2.) Make tasks explained in https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04/.
3.) In case you need still some additional other software,  download from Ubuntu Application Centre the programs which Ubuntu 18.04 supports. Keep in mind next Ubuntu LTS (version 20.04) will be launched next year spring.

(Before any installation remember to make safety copy of all your works somewhere.)

According to my experience tasks 1.) and 2.) will time your time about 1,5h.

Comment: So you seem to be recommending that I not attempt to use anything that didn't come from Canonical?  What about applications that do things I can't do with Canonical apps?  Apps that work the way I'm used to (so I don't have so much new stuff to learn every two years)?  Apps that make my computer *mine* instead of just another Ubuntu clone?

Comment: It's a heck of a lot easier if you use the version of an app supported within the distro, and if you have a chance to do that, I'd suggest it. If a package ain't part of the distro, keep it, don't throw it away.

Comment: @K7AAY Sure, it's a lot easier if I let Microsoft run my life, too, but truth is, I hate Firefox and Chrome, need Skype (and can't use another similar app to talk to Skype users), and get massively outdated versions of Wine from the Ubuntu repos for my then-current version.  Never mind needing genuine Java.  Ubuntu isn't complete; if it were, I might be able to use only supported programs.  Oh, yeah, BOINC isn't up to date on the repos, either.

Comment: If a package ain't part of the distro, keep it, don't throw it away.

Comment: Skype works fine with/within Ubuntu 18.04.